# java.lang.RuntimeException: javax.mail.MessagingException: Could not connect to SMTP host: smtp.gmail.com, port: 465

Tags: java, eclipse, smtp, jakarta-mail

Hello people of stackoverflow!

I've been trying my hands on the JavaMail API

```
// Recipient's email ID needs to be mentioned.
          String to = "toaddrs@gmail.com";//change accordingly

          // Sender's email ID needs to be mentioned
          String from = "fromaddrs@gmail.com";//change accordingly
          final String email = "emailaddrs@gmail.com";//change accordingly
          final String password = "xxxxxxxxx";//change accordingly

          // Assuming you are sending email through relay.jangosmtp.net
          String host = "smtp.gmail.com";

          Properties props = new Properties();
          props.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");
          props.put("mail.smtp.starttls.enable", "true");
          props.put("mail.smtp.host", host);
          props.put("mail.smtp.port", "465");

          // Get the Session object.
          Session session = Session.getInstance(props,
          new javax.mail.Authenticator() {
             protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
                return new PasswordAuthentication(email, password);
             }
          });

          try {
             // Create a default MimeMessage object.
             Message message = new MimeMessage(session);

             // Set From: header field of the header.
             message.setFrom(new InternetAddress(from));

             // Set To: header field of the header.
             message.setRecipients(Message.RecipientType.TO,
             InternetAddress.parse(to));

             // Set Subject: header field
             message.setSubject("Testing Subject");

             // Now set the actual message
             message.setText("Hello, this is sample for to check send "
                + "email using JavaMailAPI ");

             // Send message
             Transport.send(message);

             System.out.println("Sent message successfully....");

          } catch (MessagingException e) {
                throw new RuntimeException(e);
          }
```

The programs seems to have no error, after executing I'm getting:

> java.lang.RuntimeException: javax.mail.MessagingException: Could not connect to SMTP host: smtp.gmail.com, port: 465;
>     nested exception is:
>       java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out: connect

Can anybody please help me out on this???
<< -> Yes, I've configured the GMail access to less secured apps' option.... >>

Thnks in advance!!

Comment: I hope that's not your real password...

Comment: Are you connected to the Internet? Using a proxy or something?

Comment: Yes there's a proxy: 
Automatic configuration script: "http://pac.zscalertwo.net/philips.com/global-pac.pac"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your firewall or proxy or anti-virus program is probably preventing direct connections.

The JavaMail FAQ has [tips for connecting through a proxy](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javamail/faq/index.html#proxy), and [debugging tips to help determine why you can't connect](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javamail/faq/index.html#condebug).

Answer (score 0):

When sending mail via Gmail SMTP server using TLS you should use port 587

```
Properties props = new Properties();
props.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");
props.put("mail.smtp.starttls.enable", "true");
props.put("mail.smtp.host", host);
props.put("mail.smtp.port", "587");
```

Port **465** is for sending email using SSL, should look something like this

```
Properties props = new Properties();
props.put("mail.smtp.host", host);
props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.port", "465");
props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.class","javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory");
props.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");
props.put("mail.smtp.port", "465");
```

Comment: Hi @anders!
Thanks for the solution..!

tried both of'em..
but no luck...

Still getting the same error!

Comment: Do you have access from your local computer? Try to telnet the different ports, this is the result from my computer:  `$telnet smtp.gmail.com 587
Trying 64.233.162.109...
Connected to gmail-smtp-msa.l.google.com.
Escape character is '^]'.
220 smtp.gmail.com ESMTP oh8sm5050lbb.29 - gsmtp` and `$ telnet smtp.gmail.com 465
Trying 64.233.162.108...
Connected to gmail-smtp-msa.l.google.com.
Escape character is '^]'.`